# Couldn't find "madExcept settings" option under the "project" directory after downloading madExcept successfully on my desktop

Tags: delphi, madexcept

I am a new user of Delphi 10.3 and my colleague recommended I use madExcept. However, after I downloaded the madExcept and installed it successfully on my desktop, I couldn't find the "madExcept settings" option under the "project" directory to enable the madExcept. Does anyone have any idea how I can make it work? Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT**

After consulting the technical staff Mathias Rauen (Thanks a lot for his patience and help!) from madExcept, I found out that my default installation path(C:\Program Files (x86)) is rather limited in access rights on OS so Delphi couldn't load madExcept packages and therefore “madExcept settings” can’t be found in Delphi.

Solution: Delete the default path information in the Registry Editor and reinstall madExcept in a path where the non-admin user also has full access.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldpbo.png)

Comment: Did you select your Delphi version during the setup?

Comment: Ask at the ME forum. And provide some more details about precisely what you did.

Comment: Sounds like you probably installed the product onto your computer, but not into the IDE itself yet

Comment: It has been some time since I used madExcept but isn't it necessary to add madExcept as first unit in the project file and then compile the project at least once so that madExcept configuration files are created in the projects directory?